# Python, functions, what is going on here? if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]

Tags: python, list, function

can anybody help me understand line 3 please?

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]:
      return False
  return True
```

Thanks

Comment: it is matching that for every element in the index element in lst1 is the value at `len(lst2) - 1 - index`  in `lst2` is same or not?

Comment: Note that `len(lst2)` is redundant here, Python indexing is always relative to the end of the list for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

What the function **reversed_list** is doing is testing if the **lst1** is the reversed version of **lst2** (the reciprocal is also true).

Lets imagine that **lst1** is:

```
lst1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

If the **lst2** is the version of **lst1** reversed, **lst2** must contains, in that order, the value below to the function returns true:

```
lst2 = [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

In this example, **len(lst1)** is equal to **4** and **len(lst2)** is also equals to **4**, so the *if* condition is verifying, on the first iteration, if the value **lst1[0** (index)**]** is equals to **lst2[4** (len(lst2)) **- 1 - 0** (index)**]**.

Observe that if the **lst2** be like below, the function **reversed_list** will also return true:

```
lst2 = [20, 15, 10, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It means:

1. `lst1[index]` = lst1's current element. Retrieved with the current looping index.
2. `lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]` = lst2's element which is the length of `lst2` substracted by 1 and the current looping index.

Overall it means that it checks whether the current looping element of `lst1` is not equal to the element at index which retrieves through the length of `lst2` substracted by one and the current index of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

- `lst1[index]` is checking the element of index position and index starts from 0.
- `lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]` is checking the `last-1` position of `lst2` and from the last it also subtract current index position.

i.e, If you check the iteration then you will get a clear thought. I am passing two list below

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Now check the iteration for the following code

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
    for index in range(len(lst1)):
        print(lst1[index], lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index])
        # if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]:
        #     return False
    return True


list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print(reversed_list(list_1, list_2))
```

Check the output for `lst1[index], lst2[len(lst2) - 1 - index]`

```
1 7
2 6
3 5
4 4
5 3
6 2
7 1
```

The first list starts from the 0th position and the last list starts from the last position. Now apply your condition hope you will make a good idea.